# Store more data in iov in C++

Tags: c++, struct, bus-error

I am writing a C++ program (see below). My goal is to store data in iov struct. I have allocated buffer of fixed length in constructor. Every time that buffer gets filled, I want to transfer data in iov and allocated new buffer of fixed length. Finally when done with data processing, I want to return iov struct. My intension here is to store all these data into iov so that if it's required in future, I can send data easily. I have written sample code. But it seems it's not working. I got an "Bus error: 10". Can someone help me?

Sample code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sys/uio.h>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;
#define MAX_LEN 1000
#define MIN_LEN    20

class MyClass
{   
    public:
        MyClass();
       ~MyClass();
        void fillData(std::string &data);

    private:
       struct iovec     *iov;
       unsigned int     count;
      unsigned int  len;
      char *buf;
      unsigned int total_len;
      unsigned int tmp_len;
};  

MyClass::MyClass()
{   
  cout << "Inside constructor" << endl;
   total_len = MIN_LEN;
   buf = (char *)malloc(MAX_LEN);
   if (buf == NULL) {
        cout << "Error: can’t allocate buf" << endl;
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
     } 
}   


MyClass::~MyClass()
{   
    free(buf);
}   

void MyClass::fillData(std::string &data)
{   
    unsigned int d_len, tmp_len, offset;
    d_len = data.size();
    const char* t = data.c_str();
    total_len += d_len;
    tmp_len += d_len;
    if (total_len > MAX_LEN) {

        /* Allocate memory and assign to iov */
        tmp_len = d_len;

     }


    memcpy(buf + offset, t,  d_len);
    /* Adjust offset */
}

int main()
{

  MyClass my_obj;
  int i;
  std::string str = "Hey, welcome to my first class!";
  for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    my_obj.fillData(str);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to use a debugger and go line by line? That should be sufficient  to spot the error. Bus error is usually linked to a segfault or some kind of illegal memory manipulation (like dereferencing a null pointer). It should be fairly  easy  to spot it using `gdb` or any debugger.

Comment: No, I didn't try using gdb. I will try and update the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without understanding the intent of your program in detail, it is very clear that you forgot to reserve memory for the `iov`-objects themselfes.
For example, in your constructor you write `iov[0].iov_base = buf`, yet `iov` has not been allocated before.

To overcome this, somewhere in your code, before the first access to `iov`, you should write something like `iov = calloc(100,sizeof(struct iovev))` or a c++ equivalent using `new[]`.

Consider the following program:

```
struct myStruct {
  char *buf;
  int len;
};

int main() {

  struct myStruct *myStructPtr;

  myStructPtr->buf = "Herbert";  // Illegal, since myStructPtr is not initialized; So even if "Herbert" is valid, there is no place to store the pointer to literal "Herbert".
  myStructPtr[0].buf = "Herbert"; // Illegal, since myStructPtr is not initialized

  // but:
  struct myStruct *myStructObj = new (struct myStruct);
   myStructObj->buf = "Herbert"; // OK, because myStructObj can store the pointer to literal "Herbert"
   myStructObj->buf = "Something else"; // OK; myStructObj can hold a pointer, so just let it point to a different portion of memory. No need for an extra "new (struct myStruct)" here
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Stephan for reply. Do I need to allocate memory for iov? I am just pointing to buf. I've already allocated memory for buff. Why is it required to allocate again? My intension is to store data into iov whenever buff gets full.

Comment: If I allocate memory for iov, don't you think I am wasting memory since I've already allocated it for buf. Just to let you know that I tried to follow your advise and it worked fine.

Comment: No, you are not wasting memory; the `iovec`-struct seems to combine a pointer to a buffer and the length of this buffer. So besides the memory to be reserved for the buffer itself, you need to reserve memory for the pointer to the buffer and for the length. Clear?

Comment: No @Stephan. Sorry but I am confused now. Can you please explain with simple example? If I do calloc, it will try to assign a new block of memory, isn't it so?

Comment: Added an example to the answer; hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for explanation. I wonder in this case, once my buf gets full, I allocate new memory. So everytime I allocate memory to buff, I need to allocate memory for iovec as well, isn't it?

Comment: No, you don't need to allocate memory for `iov` again if you just exchange values therein. just let `iov` point to a different portion of memory (and don't forget to free the previous buffer). See also adapted answer.

Comment: Ohh, I got your point. Thanks! One last thing. In your example, `myStructObj->buf = "Something else"` will loose the earlier content. I would like to store all my data. For example, once the buf is full, I would like to save my data into iov[0]. Will allocate new memory for buf. Again this gets full, i will save my data into iov[1] and so on.

Comment: Yes, right. When assigning `myStructObj->buf = "Something else"`, one will "loose" the information where the previous content lies. If the previous content is still relevant, you'd have to - as you said - #use `iov[1]..iov[n]` for new content.

Comment: Okay. One more thing. I am actually writing a library where I need to dynamically allocate memory for iov pointers and another memory for iov elements. I am planning to write a kind of link list to maintain these iovs. Is it correct approach? I heard about std::list but I don't know how can I use it in this program since I have to written all these iovs? Can you please help me or point me to some reference?

Answer (score 0):

I took your code, which didn't exactly use anything with the `iovec`, and I modified it a little.

I am not sure why developers prefer buffers of `char*` instead of `std::string`
or why use a pointer which should be allocated and then deleted instead of using a `std::vector`

I also added a function which uses the iovec. It is called `void MyClass::print_data()`. It prints all the data in the vector `iovecs`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/uio.h>

using namespace std;

class MyClass
{
        vector<struct iovec> iovs;
        vector<string> bufs;
public:
        MyClass();
        ~MyClass();
        void fill_data(const string &data);
        void print_data();
};

MyClass::MyClass()
{
        cout << "Inside constructor" << endl;
}


MyClass::~MyClass()
{
}

void MyClass::fill_data(const string &data)
{
        stringstream stream;
        stream << setw(2) << setfill(' ') << (this->bufs.size() + 1) << ". "
                 << data << endl;
        this->bufs.push_back(stream.str());
        iovec iov = {&(bufs.back()[0]), bufs.back().size()};
        this->iovs.push_back(iov);
}

void MyClass::print_data() {
        writev(STDOUT_FILENO, iovs.data(), iovs.size());
}

int main() {
        MyClass my_obj;
        string str = "Hey, welcome to my first class!";
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
                my_obj.fill_data(str);
        }

        my_obj.print_data();
        return 0;
}
```

compile it like so: `g++ test.cpp`